# Why is document.getElementById() returning null in React although element is there in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have this code inside a React class component and when I try calling `document.getElementById(photo._id)` it keeps returning null although when I tried `console.log(photo._id)` in both lines, the line in the render is printed first in the console so the id is supposed to be there?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.location.state.product.photos.map((photo) => {
      return axios
        .get(`${SERVER_HOST}/products/photo/${photo.filename}`)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data) {
            if (res.data.errorMessage) {
              console.log(res.data.errorMessage);
            } else {
              console.log(photo._id);
              console.log(document.getElementById(photo._id));
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Record not found");
          }
        });
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
    {this.props.location.state.product.photos.map((photo) => {
         { console.log(photo._id); }
         <img key={photo._id} id={photo._id} />;
   
     })}
  )
}
```

[Here is a picture of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ80Z.png)

Comment: question should be, why are you using DOM in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the image element in map function. Hence, it's not mounted in the dom tree and you can't access it using document.getElementById()

```
render() {
    return (
    {this.props.location.state.product.photos.map((photo) => {
         { console.log(photo._id); }
          {/** return keyword is missing here **/}
         return <img key={photo._id} id={photo._id} />;
   
     })}
  )
}
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much it works now, I didn't know I need to do that 

Comment: If the curly braces are not present. Then an explicit return is not needed. But, if it's within bracket. You have to specify return. If it worked you can mark it solved. Upvotes are always welcome :P

Comment: Thank you for that, I really wanna upvote but it doesnt let me

Comment: Helping a fellow coder is top priority than upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Replace your render function body with the code below.

```js
return this.props?.location?.state?.product?.photos?.map((photo) => 
   <img key={photo._id} id={photo._id} src={...} />;
```

Comment: This works too, the curly brackets were the problem. Thank you! 